# Simple Discord bot not functioning as its supposed to be |Python

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I have recently started coding with python and ended up coding a discord bot.
This is the code i ran:

```
import discord
client = discord.Client()


@client.event
async def help(message):
   if message.author == client.user:
    return
if message.content.startswith("!help"):
    await message.channel.send("Commands:!hello, !help ")
client.run(The token im obviously not going to share)
```

I think this should make the bot say:Commands:!hello, !help, when a user writes !help
but in the end nothing happens.
Anyone got an idea how i can improve the code so it works?Id love to know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event's name is `on_message`:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message): 
    if message.author == client.user: 
        return 
    if message.content.startswith("!help"):
        await message.channel.send("Commands:!hello, !help ")
```